# ResNet50の転移学習にて、想定した形状のTensorが出力できない

Tags: python, 深層学習, pytorch

pretrain済みのResNet50の構造を変更して利用したいのですが、
変更後のモデルから、想定していたような形状の出力が得られません。

次のコードで、

モデルの構造を変更し,torchinfoで確認すると

```
def Custom_ResNet50():
    model=torchvision.models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
    model.avgpool=nn.Sequential(
                                nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=(1,1)),
                                nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=2048,out_channels=1024,kernel_size=4,stride=1,padding=0),
                                nn.BatchNorm2d(1024),
                                nn.ReLU(),
                                nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=1024,out_channels=512,kernel_size=4,stride=2,padding=1),
                                nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
                                nn.ReLU(),
                                nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=512,out_channels=256,kernel_size=4,stride=2,padding=1),
                                nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
                                nn.ReLU(),
                                nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=256,out_channels=128,kernel_size=4,stride=2,padding=1),
                                nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
                                nn.ReLU(),
                                nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=128,out_channels=64,kernel_size=4,stride=2,padding=1),
                                nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
                                nn.ReLU(),
                                nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=64,out_channels=32,kernel_size=4,stride=2,padding=1),
                                nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
                                nn.ReLU(),
                                nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=32,out_channels=16,kernel_size=4,stride=2,padding=1),
                                nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
                                nn.ReLU(),
                                nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=16,out_channels=1,kernel_size=4,stride=2,padding=1),
                                nn.ReLU(),
                                
                                )

    model.fc = nn.Identity()
    return model
batch_size=8
summary(model=Custom_ResNet50(),input_size=(batch_size,3,512,512))
```

結果

```
ResNet                                   [8, 262144]               --
├─Conv2d: 1-1                            [8, 64, 256, 256]         9,408
├─BatchNorm2d: 1-2                       [8, 64, 256, 256]         128
├─ReLU: 1-3                              [8, 64, 256, 256]         --
├─MaxPool2d: 1-4                         [8, 64, 128, 128]         --
├─Sequential: 1-5                        [8, 256, 128, 128]        --
│    └─Bottleneck: 2-1                   [8, 256, 128, 128]        --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-1                  [8, 64, 128, 128]         4,096
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-2             [8, 64, 128, 128]         128
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-3                    [8, 64, 128, 128]         --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-4                  [8, 64, 128, 128]         36,864
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-5             [8, 64, 128, 128]         128
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-6                    [8, 64, 128, 128]         --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-7                  [8, 256, 128, 128]        16,384
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-8             [8, 256, 128, 128]        512
│    │    └─Sequential: 3-9              [8, 256, 128, 128]        16,896
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-10                   [8, 256, 128, 128]        --
│    └─Bottleneck: 2-2                   [8, 256, 128, 128]        --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-11                 [8, 64, 128, 128]         16,384
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-12            [8, 64, 128, 128]         128
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-13                   [8, 64, 128, 128]         --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-14                 [8, 64, 128, 128]         36,864
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-15            [8, 64, 128, 128]         128
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-16                   [8, 64, 128, 128]         --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-17                 [8, 256, 128, 128]        16,384
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-18            [8, 256, 128, 128]        512
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-19                   [8, 256, 128, 128]        --
│    └─Bottleneck: 2-3                   [8, 256, 128, 128]        --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-20                 [8, 64, 128, 128]         16,384
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-21            [8, 64, 128, 128]         128
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-22                   [8, 64, 128, 128]         --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-23                 [8, 64, 128, 128]         36,864
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-24            [8, 64, 128, 128]         128
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-25                   [8, 64, 128, 128]         --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-26                 [8, 256, 128, 128]        16,384
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-27            [8, 256, 128, 128]        512
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-28                   [8, 256, 128, 128]        --
├─Sequential: 1-6                        [8, 512, 64, 64]          --
│    └─Bottleneck: 2-4                   [8, 512, 64, 64]          --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-29                 [8, 128, 128, 128]        32,768
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-30            [8, 128, 128, 128]        256
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-31                   [8, 128, 128, 128]        --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-32                 [8, 128, 64, 64]          147,456
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-33            [8, 128, 64, 64]          256
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-34                   [8, 128, 64, 64]          --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-35                 [8, 512, 64, 64]          65,536
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-36            [8, 512, 64, 64]          1,024
│    │    └─Sequential: 3-37             [8, 512, 64, 64]          132,096
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-38                   [8, 512, 64, 64]          --
│    └─Bottleneck: 2-5                   [8, 512, 64, 64]          --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-39                 [8, 128, 64, 64]          65,536
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-40            [8, 128, 64, 64]          256
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-41                   [8, 128, 64, 64]          --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-42                 [8, 128, 64, 64]          147,456
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-43            [8, 128, 64, 64]          256
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-44                   [8, 128, 64, 64]          --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-45                 [8, 512, 64, 64]          65,536
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-46            [8, 512, 64, 64]          1,024
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-47                   [8, 512, 64, 64]          --
│    └─Bottleneck: 2-6                   [8, 512, 64, 64]          --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-48                 [8, 128, 64, 64]          65,536
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-49            [8, 128, 64, 64]          256
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-50                   [8, 128, 64, 64]          --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-51                 [8, 128, 64, 64]          147,456
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-52            [8, 128, 64, 64]          256
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-53                   [8, 128, 64, 64]          --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-54                 [8, 512, 64, 64]          65,536
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-55            [8, 512, 64, 64]          1,024
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-56                   [8, 512, 64, 64]          --
│    └─Bottleneck: 2-7                   [8, 512, 64, 64]          --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-57                 [8, 128, 64, 64]          65,536
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-58            [8, 128, 64, 64]          256
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-59                   [8, 128, 64, 64]          --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-60                 [8, 128, 64, 64]          147,456
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-61            [8, 128, 64, 64]          256
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-62                   [8, 128, 64, 64]          --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-63                 [8, 512, 64, 64]          65,536
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-64            [8, 512, 64, 64]          1,024
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-65                   [8, 512, 64, 64]          --
├─Sequential: 1-7                        [8, 1024, 32, 32]         --
│    └─Bottleneck: 2-8                   [8, 1024, 32, 32]         --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-66                 [8, 256, 64, 64]          131,072
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-67            [8, 256, 64, 64]          512
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-68                   [8, 256, 64, 64]          --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-69                 [8, 256, 32, 32]          589,824
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-70            [8, 256, 32, 32]          512
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-71                   [8, 256, 32, 32]          --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-72                 [8, 1024, 32, 32]         262,144
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-73            [8, 1024, 32, 32]         2,048
│    │    └─Sequential: 3-74             [8, 1024, 32, 32]         526,336
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-75                   [8, 1024, 32, 32]         --
│    └─Bottleneck: 2-9                   [8, 1024, 32, 32]         --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-76                 [8, 256, 32, 32]          262,144
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-77            [8, 256, 32, 32]          512
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-78                   [8, 256, 32, 32]          --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-79                 [8, 256, 32, 32]          589,824
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-80            [8, 256, 32, 32]          512
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-81                   [8, 256, 32, 32]          --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-82                 [8, 1024, 32, 32]         262,144
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-83            [8, 1024, 32, 32]         2,048
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-84                   [8, 1024, 32, 32]         --
│    └─Bottleneck: 2-10                  [8, 1024, 32, 32]         --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-85                 [8, 256, 32, 32]          262,144
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-86            [8, 256, 32, 32]          512
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-87                   [8, 256, 32, 32]          --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-88                 [8, 256, 32, 32]          589,824
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-89            [8, 256, 32, 32]          512
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-90                   [8, 256, 32, 32]          --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-91                 [8, 1024, 32, 32]         262,144
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-92            [8, 1024, 32, 32]         2,048
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-93                   [8, 1024, 32, 32]         --
│    └─Bottleneck: 2-11                  [8, 1024, 32, 32]         --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-94                 [8, 256, 32, 32]          262,144
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-95            [8, 256, 32, 32]          512
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-96                   [8, 256, 32, 32]          --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-97                 [8, 256, 32, 32]          589,824
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-98            [8, 256, 32, 32]          512
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-99                   [8, 256, 32, 32]          --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-100                [8, 1024, 32, 32]         262,144
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-101           [8, 1024, 32, 32]         2,048
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-102                  [8, 1024, 32, 32]         --
│    └─Bottleneck: 2-12                  [8, 1024, 32, 32]         --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-103                [8, 256, 32, 32]          262,144
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-104           [8, 256, 32, 32]          512
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-105                  [8, 256, 32, 32]          --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-106                [8, 256, 32, 32]          589,824
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-107           [8, 256, 32, 32]          512
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-108                  [8, 256, 32, 32]          --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-109                [8, 1024, 32, 32]         262,144
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-110           [8, 1024, 32, 32]         2,048
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-111                  [8, 1024, 32, 32]         --
│    └─Bottleneck: 2-13                  [8, 1024, 32, 32]         --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-112                [8, 256, 32, 32]          262,144
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-113           [8, 256, 32, 32]          512
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-114                  [8, 256, 32, 32]          --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-115                [8, 256, 32, 32]          589,824
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-116           [8, 256, 32, 32]          512
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-117                  [8, 256, 32, 32]          --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-118                [8, 1024, 32, 32]         262,144
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-119           [8, 1024, 32, 32]         2,048
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-120                  [8, 1024, 32, 32]         --
├─Sequential: 1-8                        [8, 2048, 16, 16]         --
│    └─Bottleneck: 2-14                  [8, 2048, 16, 16]         --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-121                [8, 512, 32, 32]          524,288
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-122           [8, 512, 32, 32]          1,024
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-123                  [8, 512, 32, 32]          --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-124                [8, 512, 16, 16]          2,359,296
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-125           [8, 512, 16, 16]          1,024
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-126                  [8, 512, 16, 16]          --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-127                [8, 2048, 16, 16]         1,048,576
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-128           [8, 2048, 16, 16]         4,096
│    │    └─Sequential: 3-129            [8, 2048, 16, 16]         2,101,248
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-130                  [8, 2048, 16, 16]         --
│    └─Bottleneck: 2-15                  [8, 2048, 16, 16]         --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-131                [8, 512, 16, 16]          1,048,576
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-132           [8, 512, 16, 16]          1,024
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-133                  [8, 512, 16, 16]          --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-134                [8, 512, 16, 16]          2,359,296
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-135           [8, 512, 16, 16]          1,024
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-136                  [8, 512, 16, 16]          --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-137                [8, 2048, 16, 16]         1,048,576
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-138           [8, 2048, 16, 16]         4,096
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-139                  [8, 2048, 16, 16]         --
│    └─Bottleneck: 2-16                  [8, 2048, 16, 16]         --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-140                [8, 512, 16, 16]          1,048,576
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-141           [8, 512, 16, 16]          1,024
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-142                  [8, 512, 16, 16]          --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-143                [8, 512, 16, 16]          2,359,296
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-144           [8, 512, 16, 16]          1,024
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-145                  [8, 512, 16, 16]          --
│    │    └─Conv2d: 3-146                [8, 2048, 16, 16]         1,048,576
│    │    └─BatchNorm2d: 3-147           [8, 2048, 16, 16]         4,096
│    │    └─ReLU: 3-148                  [8, 2048, 16, 16]         --
├─Sequential: 1-9                        [8, 1, 512, 512]          --
│    └─AdaptiveAvgPool2d: 2-17           [8, 2048, 1, 1]           --
│    └─ConvTranspose2d: 2-18             [8, 1024, 4, 4]           33,555,456
│    └─BatchNorm2d: 2-19                 [8, 1024, 4, 4]           2,048
│    └─ReLU: 2-20                        [8, 1024, 4, 4]           --
│    └─ConvTranspose2d: 2-21             [8, 512, 8, 8]            8,389,120
│    └─BatchNorm2d: 2-22                 [8, 512, 8, 8]            1,024
│    └─ReLU: 2-23                        [8, 512, 8, 8]            --
│    └─ConvTranspose2d: 2-24             [8, 256, 16, 16]          2,097,408
│    └─BatchNorm2d: 2-25                 [8, 256, 16, 16]          512
│    └─ReLU: 2-26                        [8, 256, 16, 16]          --
│    └─ConvTranspose2d: 2-27             [8, 128, 32, 32]          524,416
│    └─BatchNorm2d: 2-28                 [8, 128, 32, 32]          256
│    └─ReLU: 2-29                        [8, 128, 32, 32]          --
│    └─ConvTranspose2d: 2-30             [8, 64, 64, 64]           131,136
│    └─BatchNorm2d: 2-31                 [8, 64, 64, 64]           128
│    └─ReLU: 2-32                        [8, 64, 64, 64]           --
│    └─ConvTranspose2d: 2-33             [8, 32, 128, 128]         32,800
│    └─BatchNorm2d: 2-34                 [8, 32, 128, 128]         64
│    └─ReLU: 2-35                        [8, 32, 128, 128]         --
│    └─ConvTranspose2d: 2-36             [8, 16, 256, 256]         8,208
│    └─BatchNorm2d: 2-37                 [8, 16, 256, 256]         32
│    └─ReLU: 2-38                        [8, 16, 256, 256]         --
│    └─ConvTranspose2d: 2-39             [8, 1, 512, 512]          257
│    └─ReLU: 2-40                        [8, 1, 512, 512]          --
├─Identity: 1-10                         [8, 262144]
```

となり
本来ならば、[8, 1, 512, 512]の出力を得たいのですが、Sequential: 1-9の出力は[8, 1, 512, 512]であるのに、最終的には出力の形状が[8, 262144]となってしまい、想定していない形状の出力になってしまいます。
もし原因がわかる方がいらっしゃいましたら、回答していただきたいです。

※追記
ResNetのソースコード（https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/main/torchvision/models/resnet.py）
を読んだのですが

```
def _forward_impl(self, x: Tensor) -> Tensor:
中略
        x = self.avgpool(x)
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
        x = self.fc(x)
```

と279行目のx = torch.flatten(x, 1)が原因ではないかと考えています。
とはいえ解決方法が思いつかない状況です。